# How to correctly fix CURL Error 60 with Laravel Socialite?

Tags: php, ssl, curl, laravel-socialite

I've spend a good part of the last couple of days reading through all the solutions on stackoverflow and google but to no avail.

So the concrete problem:
I purchased an SSL certificate from namecheap for my webpage. This particular site is hosted on Amazon EC2, on an Amazon AMI (1).

The site is reachable through HTTPS, and even http://ssllabs.com confirms that both the ssl and the ca bundle are in good shape. However laravel socialite throws a curl 60 error peer cert not valid.

I've double and triple checked that everything is ok on the php.ini on the curl path, so no clue.

The weirdest part is that if i use the cert from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html it works just fine!

So excuse the novice question, but am I SUPPOSED to use this cert for CURL? And another different set for https?

Thanks!

Update:

I've updated my php.ini with the cacert.pem path downloaded from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

```
[curl]
; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This is required to be an
; absolute path.
curl.cainfo="/var/www/html/cacert.php"
```

And now im getting a 77 error:

```
"cURL error 77:  (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)"
```

Comment: You need to give curl a certificate bundle. It's probably not configured well on your system.

Comment: HI @Evert. Thats what I thought, but if it wasnt then https would be throwing errors right? On every browser its showing that both the main cert and the bundle is valid

Comment: No, browsers have their own bundles or use the operating system bundle. Your server probably also has a default certificate bundle. Your curl is simply not using it, so it considered every SSL certificate unverified. 

You should either use your operating system's ca bundle, or you could use the one from curl. In either case you need to make sure it stays updated.

Comment: Yes, your server may already have the certificate installed, but do you use it with your CURL call? Its not happening automatically..

Comment: The curl call is being made by the socialite framework, but ive set the correct path in the php.ini. Now the error has changed to #77, which is weird because im using the cacert provided by https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html 
I have no clue where to go from here

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out!

When I was setting up the SSL certificates for the webserver I wrote over the ca-bundle.crt on the route /etc/pki/tls/certs

Even though I was updating the configuration for the SSL at the php.ini and the ssl.conf files, CURL didnt want to play along. Reverting the changes and using the original server certificate fixed CURL, and i just renamed the https certificate.

Hope this helps someone with a similar problem.